# Estimating the distribution of the variable importance measure for PIMP

Tags: hypothesis-testing, estimation, importance, variable

In my script it says that the variable importance measure called PIMP is calculated the following way:

1. For $m=1...M$
2. permute $y$ and train model $f^{[m]}$ and estimate the generalization error $\hat{GE}(f^{[m]})$
3. Estimate the generalization error of $f^{[m]}$ on a test-set where $x_j$ is permuted: $\hat{GE}_j(f^{[m]})$
4. calculate the difference between the estimated generalization error with and without permuted $x_j$, i.e. $\hat{GE}(f^{[m]})- \hat{GE}_j(f^{[m]})$

We then use this data to estimate the distribution of the variable importance measure under the $H_0$ of $x_j$ having no effect (supposedly)

However as I understand it, this gives us the distribution of the variable importance of $x_j$ under the $H_0$ that **none** of the features has an effect on $y$. But this is not what we want, as our $H_0$ is only that $x_j$ has no effect.